# Dojo : Layout widgets inside the Custom widget

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

I have a Custom dojo widget with dojo layout widgets

template as below

```
<div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="gutters:false" id="mainPanel" style="padding: 0px">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top', splitter:false"  style="padding: 0px">
            Saartha Labs Pvt Ltd
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top', gutters: false, splitter:false"  style="padding: 0px" >
            <div id="toolBar"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="map-div"  data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center', splitter:false"></div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom', splitter:false" style="display: none" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the Custom Widget as below "Canvas.js"

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./canvas.html",

    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
], function (declare, _WidgetBase,_WidgetsInTemplateMixin, _OnDijitClickMixin,_TemplatedMixin, template) {

    return declare([_WidgetBase,_OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin,_WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: template
        //  your custom code goes here

    });

});
```

When use try to use the Canvas with new
it throws a error as below.

```
require([
        "bhuvi/canvas/Canvas",
        "dojo/domReady!"],
            function(Canvas){
                var canvas = new Canvas();
                canvas.placeAt(window.document.body);
            });
```

Error as

"Tried to register widget with id==mainPanel but that id is already registered"

Comment: This error occurs, when you try to register a widget ( in this case the BorderContainer ) twice, while it's in first instance still, how should i say, alive. Have you checked if your widget isn't build double?

Comment: this is test code.. so its not initializing twice.. according to doc we can not put the layout widgets inside the template..

Comment: I don't see a reason why one shouldn't use layout widgets in the templates, quite the opposite. Just make sure you don't initialize the widget twice (from markup maybe?) and be careful with those ID's as per answer below.

Comment: From the api doc [link] http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html#dijit-widgetsintemplatemixin The dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin mixin does not support adding layout widgets as children. In particular there are issues with startup() and resize() calls to the children.

Answer (score 0):

Never use IDs in your widget templates. IDs must be unique, so unless your ID is dynamically generated (which isn't in this case), your ID won't be unique if you create multiple instances of your widget.

In stead of that, use the `data-dojo-attach-point` mechanism, for example:

```html
<div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="gutters:false"
        data-dojo-attach-point="mainPanel" style="padding: 0px">
        <!-- Rest of the code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can use `this.mainPanel` if you need access to that widget.

Even if you don't create multiple instances of your widget, you're still better off by using the attach points, you never know what happens behind the screens.

---

A small side note: Layout widgets are not officially supported by the `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` mixin, so be careful when using them. However, this is not the cause of your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            parseOnLoad: false
}
```

parseOnLoad should be false

Comment: This is not the cause of your issue though. The error you get is because, like @MiBrock and I said, that, due to the IDs, it's having problems to initialize the widget. As you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TX3q3/, you can use layout widgets for some cases, though not officially supported.

Comment: yes you are right.. when i use the widget <div data-dojo-type="bhuvi/canvas/Canvas"></div> its fine... problem is in the programmatic way of initializing it

Comment: when i made the parseOnLoad: false, in dojoConfig its fine.. i think that is the issue

Comment: The fiddle link I provided uses `parseOnLoad: true` and is working fine as well. That's not the problem either... I already told you what the problem is: don't use IDs in your widgets.

Comment: don't you have parser.parse() somewhere? with parseOnLoad and .parse() you would run into a problem you are describing